# Assigning a Label to a Fixed Memory Location in MSP430 Assembly

Tags: pointers, assembly, msp430

I have been trying but could not figure out how to assign a label to a fixed memory location in assembly programming of MSP430. I want to create two pointers (e.g., xPtr and yPtr) which point to fixed memory locations in MSP430 address space. Then using the absolute mode, I want to perform instructions (e.g., Mov.b &xPtr, &yPtr).

Comment: See <iomacros.h> for how the MCU registers are defined. Which assembler are you using?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I'm using CCS v.6.

Comment: And which assembler? TI or GNU?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As shown in sections 4.8.4 and 5.10 of the [MSP430 assembler manual (SLAU131)](http://www.ti.com/lit/pdf/slaa131), you can use the `.set` or `.equ` directives to assign a value to a symbol:

```
xPtr    .set 1234h
yPtr    .set 5678h

        MOV.B &xPtr, &yPtr
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!